Linode NodeBalancer
how to listen to multiple domains on port 443 using a Linode NodeBalancer, despite the limitation of not being able to configure port 443 multiple times.
I have multiple domain in single code and multiple Linode instance I configure one domain in one NodeBalancer but how to configure multiple domain in single NodeBalancer to port 443 ?
